# Entry tags are lost when saving Stash set_list

Tags: stash

I'm using the MVVC approach and all works well until I turn on fragment caching. This works, but of course does not offer any performance advantages.

```
`{exp:stash:set_list 
        name="tutorials" 
        parse_tags="yes"
        parse_conditionals="yes"
        parse_depth="2"
    }

        {exp:channel:entries 
            channel="tutorials"
            dynamic="no" 
            disable="member_data"
        }   
            {stash:item-entry-id}{entry_id}{/stash:item-entry-id}
            {stash:entry-title}{title}{/stash:entry-title}
            {exp:stash:set_list:nested 
                name="tags"
                context="{entry_id}"
                parse_tags="yes"
            }
                {exp:tagger:tags entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                    {stash:tag-url-name}{tagger:urlsafe_tagname}{/stash:tag-url-name}
                    {stash:tag-name}{tagger:tag_name}{/stash:tag-name}
                {/exp:tagger:tags}
        {/exp:channel:entries} 
    {/exp:stash:set_list}`
```

If I set it to save using the following parameters, the tags are not shown anymore:

```
{exp:stash:set_list 
        name="tutorials" 
        parse_tags="yes"
        parse_conditionals="yes"
        parse_depth="2"
        save="yes"
        scope="site"
        refresh="5"
        replace="no"
    }
```

My layout template where I get the tags looks like this (other markup and stash data removed for clarity):

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="tutorials" paginate="bottom" limit="10"}
    <p class="custom meta">
    <span class="fa fa-tags">
    {exp:stash:get_list:nested 
        name="tags" 
        context="{item-entry-id}" 
        prefix="nested" 
        backspace="2"}
        <a href="/search/tag/{nested:tag-url-name}" rel="tag">{nested:tag-name}</a>,      
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

I suspect it is caching the first set_list data before it actually parses the nested list that gets the tag data. I did try to use:

```
{stash:embed:layouts:listing-text parse_stage="both"}
```

But that didn't work.

Maybe this approach (using a set_list) isn't the best way to do this. The page is a listing of entries and I want to be able to use pagination and switchee cases to allow for displaying filtered content by category and tag using regex with switchee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding on your get_list tag `scope=site` I seem to recall this being a thing.

Comment: Thanks. I could swear I did try that and it didn't work. When I came back to it this morning it did have the scope parameter in there. When I set them all to site it works just like it should. Another reason to walk away from a problem, it was late, I was tired, and I must have missed something in my trial and error (not saving the file after adding scope?

Comment: One other observation. It only works when set to "site". If I try to use local, the page uses the same memory and queries as when I don't save the list. I think I may need to pass along something else so it knows what page it is used on. For now "site" works and I don't think that will be a problem.

Comment: I pushed the changes to development and I saw the same strange behavior. Tags would get lost on the second page load (loading the saved data). However since I saw that with local...didn't work, then a period of time late it did work...I figured it has something to do with the timing of the save data. It needs to go through a cycle before it works as it should. 

Sure enough, I left it for the 5 minutes I had set for "refresh" and now it is working correctly. 

Exactly why it works that way the first time I'm not sure. If it will happen again, also unsure.